# Start ruby app as service on CentOS 7

Tags: ruby, centos7

I have a ruby script (actually an example script from the [Oxidized project](https://github.com/ytti/oxidized/blob/master/extra/syslog.rb)), which is written in Ruby and opens a UDP port (514) listening for syslog messages and executing some code in the background.

The system runs on CentOS 7. I want to start this script as "service" automatically when the OS boots. The script however needs to run as a specific user (oxidized) and should be controllable using normal "service ... [start|stop|status|...|" behaviour. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup services can be managed by 2 different boot systems.

CentOS6 uses System V (Old Boot System)

CentOS7 uses Systemd (New Boot System) (Systemd does support System V scripts.)

Here is a link "How to write startup script for systemd"
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd

Here is a link "How to write a System V init script to start, stop, and restart my own application or service"
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html